# Store results of a php foreach loop as an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am using a foreach loop to generate a set of thumbnail links. I am using Wordpress and for one reason or another the place my PHP is executing is not the place I would like to render the list. So my question is: can I replace the echo statement with something that will store all of the generated html (for each image, not just the last one) and allow me to generate it further down the same page?

Thanks for any help. Here's my php so far:

```
foreach ($gallery_images as $galleryID) {
    $attachment = get_post( $galleryID );

    $thumb_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $galleryID, 'thumbnail' );    //thumbnail src
    $full_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $galleryID, 'full' );  //full img src

    echo '<a href="' . $full_img[0] . '" id="description-button-' . $gallery_images_count . '" class="thumbLink" target="_blank"><img src="' . $thumb_img[0] .'"></a>';

    $gallery_images_count++;

}//end forEach
```

Comment: Instead of `echo ...` a `$html[] = ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the results to an array so that you can "echo" the results later:

```
$links = array();
foreach ($gallery_images as $galleryID) {
    $attachment = get_post( $galleryID );

    $thumb_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $galleryID, 'thumbnail' );    //thumbnail src
    $full_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $galleryID, 'full' );          //full img src

    $links[] = '<a href="' . $full_img[0] . '" id="description-button-' . $gallery_images_count . '" class="thumbLink" target="_blank"><img src="' . $thumb_img[0] .'"></a>';

    $gallery_images_count++;

}
```

And then later in your code, you can print it out:

```
echo implode("\n", $links);
```

Comment: that's perfect thank you so much for your help. Just out of interest, what does implode do?

Comment: It combines the elements of your array into one big string, separated by a delimiter (the first argument). Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array();
foreach(...) {
   $arr[] = '<a href=........';
}
```